# Why container is the outside of body

Tags: css, width, document-body

Why the container is the outside of body?
I want to content have 100% width of all body, not body and header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dsfsd</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styl.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="doc">
            <header class="topbar"></header>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#doc {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
.topbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

Please, help mi with this problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your container width to be the width of the body change `.container` to `width:100%;` instead of giving it a `px` width.  If that is what you are asking.